# How to pass parameters through a SOAP Message to consume a parameterized method of a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have written a java SOAP WebService. and a consumer as well. if I send a SOAP message to a method with no parameters. it works all fine, a proper response is recieved.

But, I am unable to consume a method that have parameters. My SOAP message is stored in following string in following pattern.

```
 String xml =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+
                            "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
                                "<S:Header/>"+
                                "<S:Body>"+
                                    "<ns2:addPerson xmlns:ns2=\"http://service.cass.com/\">"+
                                        "<fName xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">vbn</fName>"+
                                        "<lName xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">yyyy</lName>"+
                                        "<gender xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">879</gender>"+
                                        "<age xsi:type=\"xsd:int\">90</age>"+
                                    "</ns2:addPerson>"+
                                "</S:Body>"+
                            "</S:Envelope>";
```

method prototype is:
public boolean addPerson(String fName, String lName, String gender, int age);

and I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/ServerSide/ws/personService
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1305)
    at com.cass.testRequest.makeSOAPRequest(testRequest.java:71)
    at com.cass.testRequest.main(testRequest.java:37)
```

Please notice that, if I send a SOAPMessage with no parameters, for a method with 0 parameters. It all works fine and I get a proper response. In my opinion, Something is wrong with the way I am passing parameters in SOAPMessage. Please suggest how to do that.

regards,
Aqif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the `xsi` or `xsd` namespaces. Try something like the following (but see comments below about correct veriosn of the namespaces):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
```

(These wouldn't be needed for your method with no parameters, which is why it worked in that case).

**Edited**: The following validates as correct XML at http://validator.w3.org/check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:addPerson xmlns:ns2="http://service.cass.com/">
        <fName xsi:type="xsd:string">vbn</fName>
        <lName xsi:type="xsd:string">yyyy</lName>
        <gender xsi:type="xsd:string">879</gender>
        <age xsi:type="xsd:int">90</age>
        </ns2:addPerson>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

though that doesn't mean it conforms to the SOAP schema...that would be the next thing to check...

**You may get problems if the client is using SOAP 1.1 and server is using SOAP 1.2 for example as I think the namespaces are different. Similarly, do not mix namespaces from the two versions - it must all be consistent.**

And I think the up-to-date namespaces for xsd and xsi are now 2001 not 1999, (my mistake, I was using an old example).

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

But refer to the specs for SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 (whichever you are using) for the definitive namespaces!

Comment: I added this, but still no luck :(

Comment: First, make sure that your XML is valid using an XML editor, in case you have any mismatched braces etc that would be hard to spot by eye. Then see if you can enable any more detailed output from the server (logging etc) to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you escaped the quotes properly in the fragment I suggested! i.e. \"

Comment: server return, "null" and "Internal Server Error", I did checked by return just true bool value from function and commenting rest of the code but still no luck :( please help

Comment: When I send a message just like yours. with newer xsi, xsd, xmlns namespaces. Server logs gives me.

"A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint."

Comment: and I fixed it :) final problem was, method was taking arguments as arg0, arg1, arg2... can you please guide me, why it is so? why they are not named with parameter names of methods or how can I do that? 

I learned alot from your guidance and especially that logging stuff really helped. 

Thank you

Comment: can you help me with this as well?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054096/getting-nullpointerexception-whill-accessing-a-webservice-how-can-i-resolve-it/9054364#9054364